# how to view all items mat-select multiple

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm using Angular Material and
I would like to know if it is possible to automatically increase the size of mat-select when I select several security groups, because today when I select several, it can only visualize the groups that fit in the mat-select space. I wanted to be able to view all security groups.

[Selected Groups - Mat-Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0sj1.jpg)

HTML:

```html
    <mat-form-field class="matfield"  appearance="outline" required>
      <mat-label>Secure Group</mat-label>
      <mat-select class="mat-select-securegroup" [formControl]="secureGroups" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let secureGroups of secureGroupsList" [value]="secureGroups">{{secureGroups}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

COMPONENT.TS:

```js
  secureGroups = new FormControl('');
  secureGroupsList: string[] = ['Secure Group 1', 'Secure Group 2', 'Secure Group 3', 'Secure Group 4', 'Secure Group 5', 'Secure Group 6'];
```